# Open two ports connexion using sockets on java

Tags: java, sockets

I would like to open a two ports connection using sockets on java but it wont work. I read here that I should use SocketChannel instead of socket but I would like to use getInput/outputStream() methods which is impossible with Socket channels. I thought of something like this:

```
public class ServeurMaitre {
    public ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    int poolSize = 15;
    Selector selector = null;
    private ExecutorService pool = null;
    boolean logged=false;
    ServeurMaitre(int port1, int port2, int size){
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port1, size);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port2, size);
            pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
            System.out.println("Serveur en marche. En attente des clients");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServeurMaitre.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    void ConnexionServeur() throws IOException {
        while(true) {               
            Socket cnx = serverSocket.accept();
            if (cnx.getLocalPort()==3333) {
                pool.execute(new EsclaveXML(cnx, this));
            }
            if(cnx.getLocalPort()==8000) {
                pool.execute(new EsclaveHTTP(cnx, this));
            }           
        }   
    }
}
```

with this main:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServeurMaitre serveur = new ServeurMaitre(8000, 3333, 1);
        serveur.Initialisation();
        serveur.ConnexionServeur();

    }
}
```

This is what both slaves are doing:

```
public class EsclaveHTTP implements Runnable{
    Socket socket = null;
    ServeurMaitre sm = null;
    public EsclaveHTTP(Socket cnx, ServeurMaitre serveurMaitre) {
        this.socket=cnx;
        this.sm=serveurMaitre;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        String message_distant = "";
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            message_distant = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        System.out.println(message_distant); //etc etc and at the end: 


        if(!socket.isClosed())
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

and the second one

```
public class EsclaveXML implements Runnable{
    Socket socket = null;
    public EsclaveXML(Socket cnx, ServeurMaitre serveurMaitre) {
        this.socket=cnx;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "8859_1"), 1024);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            InputStream ch = socket.getInputStream();
            //System.out.println(ch);
            try {
                SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
                parser.parse(ch, new ParseurXML());
            }catch (DOMException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        finally {
            try { if(socket != null) socket.close();}
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

But it would only accept one connexion.

How could I do some sort of a parallel connexion?

Comment: Did you mean you want a read/write connection between the client and server? Why can't you just call getInputStream and getOutputStream with normal socket api?

Comment: Actually the goal is to have a server running on two ports. *One receiving http connexion (from the browser) and treating them and the second receiving xml code from a console client. I will edit my post to show you what both slaves are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwritting serverSocket variable

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port1, size);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port2, size);
```

so you are only accepting connections for the second one. You need two variables, serverSocket1 and serverSocket2 and call accept() on both.

Comment: How would I guarantee the parallel accepting of connexions then ??

Comment: I tried that. But now t2 seems to be waiting for the execution of t1 (t1 and t2 are the two threads) to execute. Can't I run them both on the same time?

Comment: @AbderrahmenMrabet: Your `Main` is calling `serveur.ConnexionServeur()`, which runs an `accept()` loop for only 1 `ServerSocket`. You need a separate `accept()` loop for each `ServerSocket`, and you should run those loops in separate threads, not in the main thread.